# Why does Perl access to cross-platform packed structs not work with SWIG?

Tags: perl, cross-platform, swig, pack

Working from:

- [Is ignoring __attribute__((packed)) always safe in SWIG interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889678)
- [Visual C++ equivalent of GCC's __attribute__ ((__packed__))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964)

My `.i` does:

```
#define __attribute__(x)
```

then uses %include to include my cross-platform definition of PACK():

```
#if defined(SWIG)
#define PACK(...) VA_ARGS
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define PACK(__Decl__) __pragma(pack(push, 1)) __Decl__ __pragma(pack(pop))
#else // GCC
#define PACK(__Decl__) __Decl__ __attribute__ ((packed))
#endif
```

Then I have code like:

```
PACK(
typedef struct {
    uint8_t something;
    uint32_t more;
} ) aName;
```

With earlier versions of the `PACK()` macro, I got syntax error from SWIG on the `typedef` line.  Now I get past that but when compiling the SWIG-generated `.c` file, I have get and set functions that complain `aName` doesn't exist.  The messages are like (edited):

```
libudr_perl_swig.c: In function '_wrap_aName_set':
libudr_perl_swig.c:2367:20: error: expected identifier or '(' before
'=' token libudr_perl_swig.c: In function '_wrap_aName_get':
libudr_perl_swig.c:2377:3: error: expected expression before 'aName'
```

SWIG sort of seems to know about my struct -- it creates access functions -- but the doesn't expose them enough that the access functions can find it.

Before I started to make this cross-platform -- when it was still Linux-only with `__attribute__ ((packed))` -- it worked in SWIG.  And it still works in Linux.  So there appears to be something about SWIG's interpretation of `PACK()` that is flawed.

The old way generated a lot of per-field code like:

```
XS(_wrap_aName_something_set) {
  {
    aName *arg1 = (aName *) 0 ;
...
```

the new way generates a little per-struct code like:

```
SWIGCLASS_STATIC int _wrap_aName_set(pTHX_ SV* sv, MAGIC * SWIGUNUSEDPARM(mg)) {
  MAGIC_PPERL
  {
```

Why should my `PACK()` (which should be a no-op in SWIG) do that?

Answer (score 0):

Googling "cpp standard variadic macros" leads to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro which notes the expansion of `...` is `__VA_ARGS__`, not `VA_ARGS` (as I had found somewhere).  When I change my macro definition to be:

```
#if defined(SWIG)
#define PACK(...) __VA_ARGS__
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define PACK(__Decl__) __pragma(pack(push, 1)) __Decl__ __pragma(pack(pop))
#else // GCC
#define PACK(__Decl__) __Decl__ __attribute__ ((packed))
#endif
```

it works.